# Replace string inside brackets containing particular characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace the honorific suffix from the name which is inside brackets 
ex Martin Koschnitzke (Dr. K) .I want the output as just Martin Koschnitzke.
Only if  the brackets contain "Dr" should be replaced

Comment: Have you made _any_ effort to solve this problem yourself before you posted here?  If so, can you include that Java code?

Comment: yes  I have used this s.replaceAll("\\([^()]*\\)", ""); but it replaces everything inside the bracket irrespective of any string inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input is:

```
String name = "Martin Koschnitzke (Dr. K)";
```

you may try this regex replacement:

```
name = name.replaceAll("\\s*\\(Dr[^)]*\\)\\s*", "");
```

This leaves the input as `Martin Koschnitzke`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(name.split("\\(")[1].contains("Dr.")) {
        name=name.split("\\(")[0];
}
```